# read browser history on ICS

Tags: android, browser-history

I'm able to get default history on Android 2.2 with the following cursor where CONTENT_URI point to `Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI`

`cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI,
                Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, null, null, null);`

```
if (cursor.moveToLast()) 
        String url = cursor.getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_URL_INDEX);
```

But it didn't work on android ICS i'm getting a wrong url and it's always the same : `1970-01-01    00:00:00    http://www.samsung.com/m-manual/common`

PS: to get the date i use `cursor.getLong(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_DATE_INDEX)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried also [getAllBookmarks()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Browser.html#getAllBookmarks%28android.content.ContentResolver%29)?

```
Cursor cursor = Browser.getAllBookmarks(getContentResolver());
if (cursor != null) {
    try {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String url = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
String sortOrder = Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE + " ASC";
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI, Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, null, null, sortOrder);
if (cursor != null) {
    try {
        if (cursor.moveToLast()) {
            String url = cursor.getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_URL_INDEX);
            long date = cursor.getLong(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_DATE_INDEX);
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Actually why the `http://www.samsung.com/m-manual/common` url is wrong? What url are you expecting? You have not specified any columns to sort by. By `cursor.moveToLast()` you are moving your cursor to the last item, not traversing the bookmarks.

Comment: i just want to get the latest visited url